# How to loop a FlatList nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

someone please can enlighten how to loop a FlatList nested array?
I know that has already a question on this topic but still no understandable how to use item params!
for exemple:
in React have
posts.jsx

```
var size = 1;
    const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <Link to={`/posts/${post.slug}`}>
          <div className="columns col-gapless" key={post.id}>
            <div className="column col-3 ">
              {post.attachments.slice(0, size).map(a => (
                <img
                  className="img-responsive"
                  key={a.id}
                  src={a.image.thumb.url}
                  alt=""
                />
              ))}
            </div>
            <div className="column col-6  ">
              <h5>{post.title}</h5>
              <p>{post.body}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
```

But posts on RN

```
_renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    let size = 1;
    const items = item.attachments
      .slice(0, size)
      .map(a => (
        <Image
          style={{ width: 100, height: 75, flex: 1 }}
          key={a.id}
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={{ uri: a.image.thumb.url }}
        />
      ));

    return (
      <View style={{ height: 100 }}>
        <View>{items}</View>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );

  };


  <FlatList
          data={this.state.posts}
          keyExtractor={(_, index) => `item-${index}`}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          onEndReached={this.onNextPage}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.01}
        />
);
```

The list render the posts but not the images from posts!
So my doubt is dont render the image because is a object or array inside the array?
and the FlatList don't work with nested array very well?
Anyway, any help would be cool!

Comment: please share sample flatList which you are using

Comment: @NagaSaiA, this is the FlatList that i'm using! have another?

Comment: I dont see any FlatList, please add to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `_renderItem` function doesn't return anything.

Unless this is a copy-paste mistake when posting the question, add a `return items;` statement at the end of `_renderItem`.

---

**Update**:
If you always only need the first image, why not just do something like this and avoid an `Array`?

```
_renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    const a = item.attachments[0];
    const items = 
        <Image
          style={{ width: 100, height: 75, flex: 1 }}
          key={a.id}
          resizeMode="cover"
          source={{ uri: a.image.thumb.url }}
        />;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you ᆼᆺᆼyes indeed was a mistake i edited my question!
but still!

So should use another return just fo the image?

Comment: Is `size` constantly `1`, or does it change?

Comment: constantly 1! the first image of the array!

Comment: @Danks In that case, why not just make `items` the `<Image>` itself, and avoid the array? Updated my answer with a sample

Comment: ᆼᆺᆼ thank you very much!
For sure is the right solution!

Comment: but still not show the image, i think that is a issue with the fetching with redux!